# Auto generate testcases for a particular Java API

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

Is there any tool (open source) that can help auto generate the test cases on the fly for a particular Java API.

The real use case is that I have a Java API for which I have written n number of test cases and have almost 100% test coverage but I want to be sure that i am not missing any use case or any erroneous condition.

Comment: If it existed, it would only be able to generate a skeleton. If it's a skeleton and you update it with real cases, it becomes harder to regenerate, partly because it has to know which are already covered. It could add identifying markers or something but that would not be very maintainable.

In conclusion: without the markers, the tool would be unable to interpret what the existing unit tests do and can not conclusively generate the "remaining" test cases. So unless you want to generate the skeleton and then manually check it against the tests you have...

Answer (score 0):

There should be numerous mutation testing tools, which can "cement" your code (with generated unit tests) against changes.

But according to your use case you need, IMO, test coverage tool like EclEmma or Cobertura to see conditions or lines of code still not tested.